# How does Stackoverflow prevent the "white flash" between page loads?

Tags: javascript, html, css, caching, browser-cache

I have noticed on StackOverflow.com (and other large professional sites such as Wikipedia.org) that when you navigate from page to page, there is no "white flash" before each page load (i.e. the pages instantly transition from one to another). I am trying to do the same thing on my page, and I have tried everything I've read about:

1. cache CSS
2. cache JavaScript
3. cache Images
4. put JavaScript at bottom of page

No matter what I try, there is still a ~10ms white "flash" that appears before each new page loads.

How does StackOverflow handle this? I am aware of other similar questions about this here but I want to know how StackOverflow does it.

Comment: How are you caching?  Are you using a service worker?

Comment: @JonathanRys I am sending a "Cache-Control: max-age=60" header along with my CSS and JavaScript. It makes a little difference but the flash is still there, even when I see that the CSS and JavaScript resources were definitely loaded from memory in my browser's developer tools.

Comment: There's still a **white flash**. Have you tried using throttling to test the site?

Comment: Your users aren't going to care about 10ms, I assure you.  Worry about more important things and performance considerations of your site.

Comment: @Jorjon "There's still a white flash" are you saying that you personally are seeing a white flash on StackOverflow?

Comment: Yes, use throttling in Chrome Dev Tools and check for yourself. With Slow 3G I see like 1 or 2 seconds of white content.

Answer (score 0):

I have actually struggled a lot with this so I will do my best to share what I've learned on my journey to kill the white flash monster.

**Tip #1:** Use a client side templating engine like React or Angular

- The reason why this is the #1 tip is because using these tools you never actually need to re-load the page which is the main culprit of the 'white flash'. At the end of the day you only have one page with React or Angular (unless you use server side rendering or something like that).

**Tip #2:** Don't change background colors/images

- If you keep the backgrounds consistent throughout your app the 'white flash' will be extremely minimal

**Tip #3:** Think about using background images.

- This is where I struggled the most with this since I needed to apply background Images after the page had technically already loaded. I still see a white flash because of this but, there are steps that I took to reduce this.

  - Use fallback background colors to use while the image is loading.
  - Compress images using https://tinypng.com/
  - Animate the image in after the image has been loaded with a cool fade-in affect

**Tip #4:** Increase your performance (i.e. minify your CSS files)

- As you already found out this only really matters on the initial load of your app but, it's still important.

In Conclusion, you will always get a white flash if you ever reload a web page. But, there are definitely things you can do reduce this even if you are not loading content with React or Angular. You will notice that the sites you listed have a white background for a reason ;)

Again, if people have other suggestions I'd love to see them but, these are the ones that I found during my own research.

[Edit] Added fallback suggestion

Comment: Bloating your site up and actually making it slower just because you're worried about this white flash is probably the worst advice.  Moving your templates and such client-side have uses, for sure, but this is not a reason.

Comment: Additionally, your advice shouldn't be "don't use background images", it should be "use a fallback background color in addition to your background images".  Some people have their browsers configured in such a way that don't even load background images.  You're going to want your text to be visible on that.

Comment: @Brad You're right that there should be a fall-back color should you decide to use background-images so I'll correct that. But, to your first point. Using client side rendering completely removes the 'white flash' issue which was the what the question was about. This question wasn't asking what rendering template to use. I never claimed that it would be the best in all scenarios.